# Tikz externalization and directory questions

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I store my exercices in the following way :

- Super directory `Base_Exos` on witch points the `$TEXINPUTS` variable.
- Sub-directories, one by class level.
- Sub-Sub-directies, one by chapter
- Sub-Sub-Sub-directories, one by exercice. This S-S-S-directory contains the text called `texte.tex` with eventually the correction called `corrige.tex` and eventually some pictures.

I can use any exercice in a main.tex file witch is far from `Base_Exos` by :

```
\input{3_eme/Droites/exo-002/texte}
```

if this `texte.tex` contains a picture reference, it is :

```
\includegraphics{3_eme/Droites/exo-002/picture-1}
```

Now, I want to use `external tikz library` and it has still compatible with my Personal Directory System and I don't want to externalize all tikzpicture, just the heavy ones.

That means, that want that the pdf picture produced by the externalization procedure are produced in the same directory than witch the `texte.tex` file is 
stored, not in the directory where `main.tex` is.

So far, I did in `main.tex` :

```
My pranbule
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize % activate
\tikzexternaldisable % disable for most pictures
\begin{document}
\input{3_eme/Droites/exo-002/texte}
\end{document}
```

in `3_eme/Droites/exo-002/texte` file

```
...
\tikzexternaldisable
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzexternaldisable
...
```

But the pdf is produced in the `main.tex` file directory instead of in the `texte.tex` one.

**Questions**

1. How to set the multiple option command to produce the pdf file in the `texte.tex` directory ?
2. How to have this pdf files independant from the `main.tex` file, ie if I include the same `texte.tex` in two different `main.tex`, no new pdf file will be produced, then no second loss of time ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I hope I fully understood what you requested. Here goes.

`\tikzexternalize` accepts a `prefix` parameter which tells `pdflatex` where to store the externalised graphics. So even if you use `\input` in `main.tex` to include exercises with `tikzpicture`s, you can set `prefix=<something>` in `main.tex` to let `pdflatex` know that externalised graphics should be stored in that directory – specifically, you want them in the directory of the exercise. You can also separate the code from the processing by saving the externalised graphics in a sub-directory where all exercises of a chapter are stored. Here I use `external` as the directory.

```
% Macro holding the exercises directory name (in main.tex).
\newcommand{\exercisesdirectory}{aclass/achapter/exercises/}
% Macro holding the externalized sub-directory (in main.tex).
\newcommand{\externaldirectory}{aclass/achapter/exercises/external/}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
% All externalized graphics go go the \externaldirectory
\tikzexternalize[prefix=\externaldirectory]
% Externalise only on-demand.
\tikzexternaldisable
```

There is a caveat, however: if your main file is not always named `main.tex`, then the `external` library will re-externalise graphics with a new filename (I believe the format is `\jobname-figureX` where `X` is a running counter starting from 0. This is not what you want; you want to avoid re-externalisation. Thankfully, this issue can be easily circumvented by letting `pdflatex` know what the externalised graphic should be named using `\tikzsetnextfilename`:

```
\tikzexternalenable
\tikzsetnextfilename{ex1fig1} % This graphic will always be named ex1fig1.
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Move along. Nothing to see here.
\end{tikzpicture}%
\tikzexternaldisable
```

This means that if this exercise is `\input` in a file `main.tex` and a file `file.tex` compiled with `pdflatex -shell-escape`, the external library will only create the figure if `ex1fig1.pdf` does not exist (or if something has changed in the `tikzpicture` environment etc.)

---

With all that in mind, your main `.tex` file would look like this:

## `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

% The path to the exercises.
\newcommand{\exercisesdirectory}{aclass/achapter/exercises/}
% The path where externalised graphics will be stored.
\newcommand{\externaldirectory}{aclass/achapter/exercises/external/}
% Will be used to store the path to the exercise to be processed.
\newcommand{\pathtoexercise}{}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
% All auxiliary files and externalised graphics go to \externaldirectory.
\tikzexternalize[prefix=\externaldirectory]
% Only externalise on-demand.
\tikzexternaldisable

% In case you want to include externalised graphics directly.
\graphicspath{ {\externaldirectory} }

\begin{document}
% This will combine the \exercisesdirectory and "firstexercise.tex" strings,
% and store them in \pathtoexercise.
\expandafter\def\expandafter\pathtoexercise\expandafter{\exercisesdirectory firstexercise.tex}
% Then we simply input \pathtoexercise.
\input{\pathtoexercise}
\end{document}
```

Where `firstexercise.tex` is stored in `aclass/achapter/exercises/`.

## `firstexercise.tex`:

```
This is some text from the first exercise. Below are some cool graphics.

\tikzexternalenable
\tikzsetnextfilename{ex1fig1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
    scale only axis,
    width=5cm,
    height=5cm,
  ]

    \addplot[red,samples=10] {rnd};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\tikzexternaldisable
```

If you want to include only externalised graphics instead of the whole `firstexercise.tex`, all you need to do is to set the `graphicspath` in `main.tex` to the `\externaldirectory`, like so: `\graphicspath{ {\externaldirectory} }`. Thereafter, you simply use `\includegraphics` with the figure filename, like so:

```
% \includegraphics will automatically search in the graphicspath directory.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{ex1fig1.pdf} % This is actually in aclass/achapter/exercises/external/ex1fig1.pdf
\caption{Exercise $1$, Figure $1$}
\label{fig:ex1fig1}
\end{figure}
```

I hope this makes at least some sense and that it is in fact what you requested.

Comment: Thank you. You perfectly understood what I want, but I didn't explain enought clearly my directory structure. As a I use `$TEXINPUT` variable, I give the input path to exercice explicitely from the root directory that is in `$TEXINPUTS`. Then I dont need all the command you use to combine the path. With a newcommand of `Input` I can set the `prefix=` and input at once, as `prefix=` is exactly the directory of the exercice I want. Thank you, with your explanaitions and example I understood better than reading the doc.

Comment: @Tarass I'm glad you figured out how to modify it to suite your use-case. Happy to have been of assistance.

Comment: @Tarass Thanks a lot for the huge bounty! It helped me break 1000 reputation points. `:-)`